# Media Slider Carousel BS3 show one image per slide on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using this Media Slider Carousel BS3 [bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/media-slider-carousel-bs3) in a web page in order to create a mini slider, however what I 'd like to do is on mobile screens to show only one image per slide instead of 3.

So instead of this

[image]

To have something like this

[image]

Comment: Show us the html code.

Comment: The html is same as the bootsnipp thats why I didnt put it in my post

Comment: Have you tried anything beyond the bootsnipp?

Comment: I thought to go with a bootstrap plugin to keep consistency with the rest elements on my web page

Comment: There is no Bootstrap plugin for this. As you know, the bootsnipp is a customization. You should make an attempt first instead of having SO figure it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like [this?](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/ygj1)

In this example they've removed two of the .col-md-4 divs and added width: 100% to the remaining .col-md-4 div - not the best approach IMO but it works.

Comment: I think the OP still wants the multiple on larger screens. This is only single.

Comment: Yes I've seen this when I was browsing these snippets to find the right one, but this one shows only one slide on desktop views. What I want to do is on large screens show 3 or 4 slides but on small screens one slide